# Late binding with assembly

Tags: c#, .net-assembly

I try to make an example of late binding. So that I understand better the difference between early binding and late binding. I try it like this:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;

namespace EarlyBindingVersusLateBinding
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Customer cust = new Customer();


            Assembly hallo = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

            Type CustomerType = hallo.GetType("EarlyBindingVersusLateBinding.cust");

            object customerInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(CustomerType);

            MethodInfo getFullMethodName = CustomerType.GetMethod("FullName");

            string[] paramaters = new string[2];
            paramaters[0] = "Niels";
            paramaters[1] = "Ingenieur";

            string fullname = (string)getFullMethodName.Invoke(customerInstance, paramaters);



            Console.WriteLine(fullname);
            Console.Read();

        }
    }

    public class Customer
    {

        public string FullName(string firstName, string lastName)
        {

            return firstName + " " + lastName;

        }

    }
}
```

but I get this exception:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Value cannot be null.
```

on this line:

```
 object customerInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(CustomerType);
```

And I can't figure out how to fix that.

Thank you.

Comment: Well, could you check, whether the variable `CustomerType` is `null`? Judging by the error it most likely is. So then the question is why `hallo.GetType("EarlyBindingVersusLateBinding.cust");` returns `null`. Most likely scenario is, that the name of the type is different. (Also I don't know of the bat, whether GetType allows relative Namespace path's) You could use `hallo.GetTypes()` and list each Type within the assembly to learn more.

Comment: It will be very obvious when you spend a bit of time to debug the code.  Assembly.GetType() returns *null* if you pass the wrong string.  Kaboom is next.  Consider "Customer" instead of "cust".  What made you type "cust" is probably the real question, hard to guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, `Assembly.GetType` apparently returned `null`. Let's check [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y0cd10tb(v=vs.95).aspx) and find out what that means:

> **Return Value**
>   Type: System.Type
>   A Type object that represents the specified class, or null if the class is not found.

So, the class `EarlyBindingVersusLateBinding.cust` could not be found. This is not surprising, since this is not a valid type in your assembly. `cust` is a local variable in your `Main` method. You probably wanted to write:

```
Type CustomerType = hallo.GetType("EarlyBindingVersusLateBinding.Customer");
```

Comment: ah, thank you!! then even this:  //Customer cust = new Customer(); is not necassary.

Comment: @LikeToDo: Exactly. If you do "real" late binding on a "foreign" assembly, you wouldn't even be able to do that, since the compiler wouldn't recognize "Customer".